# Three.js shadows quality update

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to make light (sun) for casting shadows to all scene (DirectionalLight is the best, right?), but the quality is bad, so I'm trying to make the settings of the shadow: on/off, Low, Normal, High:

a = 512 ... 8192; b = 300 ... 8000

```
    light.castShadow = checked; - no update (but if reload an objects it is work)

    light.shadow.mapSize.width/height = a; - this works

    light.shadow.camera.top/bottom/left/right = b; - no updating
```

Tried to see the changes, but nothing works:

```
light.shadow.camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); - shadows disappear at all
scene.updateMatrixWorld();
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
camera.updateMatrixWorld();
camera.updateMatrix();
```

Is the any better way to do a sun?
And how to redraw the shadows?

Adding an example to better understand what I mean ->
[Example](https://s31.postimg.org/lmw07ztsb/image.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to this link: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

> Properties that can't be easily changed in runtime (once material is
>   rendered at least once):
>
> - numbers and types of uniforms
> - numbers and types of lights
> - presence or not of: texture, fog, vertex colors, skinning, morphing, shadow map, alpha test
>
> Changes in these require building of new shader program. You'll need to set material.needsUpdate flag to true.

Comment: Thenk you for reply, but in doesn't help. The problem is same: just part of scene (in the center) has shadows.. [Example](https://s31.postimg.org/lmw07ztsb/image.png) to better understand

Comment: @IgorErsgow Ok. If you increase the camera planes (top, right, etc) you need to increase your shadow maps size too. If you set b = 8000, then a = 8k (for instance). If you need to change shadow quality on the fly, I think the easiest way to do this is making several light instances and activate the one you choose.

Comment: thank you for your reply! I understand what you are talking about, but it seems like you didn't get a question. Can you, please, watch an example in question (The last link). There I tried to draw the problem.... I thought about several light too, but I think it's not the best way to make allscene shadows with good quality.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change shadow mapSize when runtime, you have to dispose()

```
light.shadow.map.dispose()
light.shadow.map = null
let s = 1024
light.shadow.mapSize = new THREE.Vector2(s, s)
```

https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-dispose-of-objects